# Webpack - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, typeerror

I'm using `vue.js` & getting Uncaught TypeError while adding `css-style` in my `vue-component`.
It seems fine when I either `import css` in `script` or just remove `css-style` from component.

I've no depth understanding about `webpack` configuration. So, should I do any changes on `webpack.config.js` file?

**The error I'm getting**

```
app.js:64 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (1.273ca42a3c140f025ab6.js:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object../node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (1.273ca42a3c140f025ab6.js:93)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Module../resources/js/views/welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (1.273ca42a3c140f025ab6.js:267)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Module../resources/js/views/welcome.vue (1.273ca42a3c140f025ab6.js:216)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at async Promise.all (:8000/index 0)
```

**Vue Component:**

```
<template>
    <div class="section">
        Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // Works fine if I import css
    import '_ANYCSS_'

    export default {
        //
    }
</script>

<!--getting TypeError if I add style section-->
<!--I've tried scoped and scss mode, neither works-->
<style>
    .section {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**Webpack Configuration** `webpack.config.js`:

```
let mix = require('../src/index');

let ComponentFactory = require('../src/components/ComponentFactory');

new ComponentFactory().installAll();

require(Mix.paths.mix());

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

let WebpackConfig = require('../src/builder/WebpackConfig');

module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();
```

Comment: You didn't provided your webpack config. What is inside '../src/builder/WebpackConfig'?